# Display current time Game Maker

Tags: datetime, game-maker

I've been trying hard to simply display the current time and couldn't find a solution anywhere...so sorry for the misplaced post.

All I want is to display the time on the user's pc or phone.

What I can do is get the time to show up in a box message but not have it just displayed and updated every second.

This is my current code

```
//store the current time
t=date_current_datetime();

//get the hour portion of that time
h=date_get_hour(t);

//get the minute portion of the time.
m=date_get_minute(t);

//get the second potion of the time
s=date_get_second(t);

//show the time
txt="The current time is:"+string(h)+":"+string(m)+":"+string(s);
show_message(txt);
```

Hope this gamemaker code makes sense, thanks for any help.

Comment: What you want? (What is your goals?) Do you know that `show_message` is only for debugging?

Comment: I want the current time to show up on the screen when you run the game and have it update every second so that it displays the time. I did not know that show_message was only for debugging

Answer (score 6):

Ok, add to `Create` event:

```
txt = "";
alarm[0] = 1;
```

Move your code to `Alarm 0` event:

```
//store the current time
t = date_current_datetime();

//get the hour portion of that time
h = date_get_hour(t);

//get the minute portion of the time.
m = date_get_minute(t);

//get the second potion of the time
s = date_get_second(t);

//show the time
txt = "The current time is: " + string(h) + ":" + string(m) + ":" + string(s);

alarm[0] = room_speed;
```

And last - `Draw` event:

```
draw_text(10, 10, txt);
```

Of course also you can use `Draw GUI` event or view coords, like

```
draw_text(view_xview[0] + 10, view_yview[0] + 10, txt);
```

Comment: Wow worked on the first go, and is exactly what I need! Thx a lot

Comment: Do you know what I would have to do to to make for example an object visible at a vertain time? I keep getting errors using h, m and s as variables.....

Comment: @Panga97 Many ways. For example, you can add to that `Alarm 0` after `txt = ....` something like: `if h = 13 and m = 00 { obj_lunch.visible = true; } else { obj_lunch.visible = false; }` where 'obj_lunch' is your object

Comment: Many people who learn GML forget to use the `var` keywords. It creates temporary variables which stop existing at the end of the code. You should add the line `var t, h, m, s;` at the beginning of the Alarm 0 script.

Comment: mm I've got this code                                                                                                             //store the current time
var t = date_current_datetime();

//get the hour portion of that time
var h = date_get_hour(t);

//get the minute portion of the time.
var m = date_get_minute(t);

//get the second potion of the time
var s = date_get_second(t);

//show the time
txt = "The current time is: " + string(h) + ":" + string(m) + ":" + string(s);

alarm[0] = room_speed;

////\\\\

if (m = 40) {

obj_Logo.visible = true;

}

Comment: I get: "
___________________________________________
############################################################################################
FATAL ERROR in
action number 1
of Alarm Event for alarm 0
for object Current_Time:

Push :: Execution Error - Variable Get 100000.obj_Logo(100005, -2147483648)
 at gml_Object_Current_Time_ObjAlarm0_1 (line 22) - obj_Logo.visible = true;
############################################################################################
"

Comment: @Panga97 see [example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78963719/stackoverflow/gml/time.gmz) - here second object will showed/hided each 10 seconds.

Comment: How do i use this example? I get a gamemaker file downloaded and don't know what to do with it :( I tried using it as an object but nope

Comment: @Panga97 what version of GM you use?

Comment: @Panga97 File -> Import project